# Java Jira HTTP response code 403

Tags: java, rest, http, jira

I'm trying to get some data by the rest api of Jira. Thiw website is locally in my enterprise and on https. The first time we go on it we are automatically login by SSO. There are certificats too.

I have check all post about this error, try with User-Agent or TrustManager but nothing work :( then I can access to the page by my browser without any problem. It's work on two other computer and I didn't really understand why.

Error I got :

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://myjira.xx/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PARE2+order+by+updated&fields=id,updated,summary,assignee,worklog&startAt=0&maxResults=30
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

And my code is :

```
    public void connectToJira() throws Exception {
    String adresse = "https://myjira.xx/";
    adresse += "rest/api/2/search?jql=project=NAMEProject+order+by+updated&fields=id,updated,summary,assignee,worklog&startAt=0&maxResults=30";

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    } };

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    URL url = new URL(adresse);

    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("myUsername:myPassword".getBytes())));

    if (401 == uc.getResponseCode()) {
        throw new Exception("Code erreur 401");
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

I try to add certificats from my cacerts but same problem :(

Thanks